# Multiple paired t-tests on microarray data

Tags: r, p-value, genome

I'm looking at mRNA expression data of thousands of genes in both metastases and main tumours from the same patients. From those with multiple metastases, all metastases get separate data. The table looks something like the one below.

```
Subjects  Type  GeneA  GeneB  GeneC
    A      Met  1      2      5
    A      Main 3      6      43
    B      Met  5      1      3
    B      Met  1      44     2
    B      Main 3      4      3
```

I want to do pairwise t-tests for each patient and gene to see which genes consistently vary between metastasis and tumour across all patients (ie compare GeneA Met/Main for patient A, B, C etc. and so on for all genes) and then adjust the p-values to keep a 5% false discovery rate. I've managed to run unpaired t-tests pooling all subjects as follows, but can't wrap my head around how to perform paired t-tests. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(multtest)
teststat<-mt.teststat(t(mydata[,3:N]),mydata[,2])#N is the last column
rawp = 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(teststat)))
procedures = c("BH")
adjusted = mt.rawp2adjp(rawp, procedures)
```

Comment: What about using pairwise t-test from base R? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/pairwise.t.test.html

Comment: Unless this is a self-study exercise, you should look at the [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) package (also see the original publication [here](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/43/7/e47)). limma has been developed to perform gene expression analyses based on microarray (and sequencing) data. It also has a very comprehensive user guide.